# In Swift, is it possible to combine both an SKScene and a UIView in the same ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

The app I am creating has a 'Stats' view controller that incorporates typical UI Elements (Labels, Buttons, ImageViews, etc...), but I also want to be able to use a sprite  with gravity on that same screen.

What is the proper way to set this up? 
Do I create a View Controller in my storyboard and then link it to a .swift file with a UIViewController class (as normal), but then create a separate class in that same swift file for an SKScene?

OR... if the SKScene class needs to be in a separate .swift file, can I link up both .swift files (UIViewController & SKScene) to that same View Controller in my storyboard?

I have no code to provide (as I don't know where to begin), but if you could point me in the right direction with a term or something to research, I would be most grateful! Enough hours have already been spent looking.

Comment: see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735628/how-can-i-add-a-single-game-scene-from-spritekit-into-a-normal-single-view-swift

Comment: Im assuming you want to create a kind of HUD? In that case, don't incorporate UIKit and SpriteKit into the same ViewController because the code can become very sloppy and complex very quickly. I recommend studying Parent/Child node relationships and having separate SKNodes to handle the HUD and scene separately.

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions :) I looked a bit deeper by following a trail of breadcrumbs lol and learned that you can apply gravity/collision effects to typical UIKit elements as well using something called 'UIKit Dynamics' (which is essentially all that I need). I found this which is a helpful overview: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-uikit-dynamics-swift-animate-apps/

Comment: UIKit Dynamics has had several significant updates giving it much more powerful features since that article, @Justin. It was good, is now great.